# Why does modifying a list affect the filtered list?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following example:

```
List<String> myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("Ford");
myList.Add("Porsche");

var filteredList = myList.Where(a => a.StartsWith("F"));

myList.Add("Ferrari");

foreach (string s in filteredList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

The output is:

```
Ford  
Ferrari
```

When I create the filtered list, the list only contains:

```
Ford
```

**Why does modifying the original list affect the filtered one?**

Comment: Why you think that is list and modified? It is enumerable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ is lazily evaluated. This means that `filteredList` does not contain `Ford` at the time you create it. All it contains is a reference to `myList` and the lambda you gave it. It's when you actually evaluate the list with your `foreach` that the filtering happens. Since the list now contains `Ferrari`, that is returned as well.

If you want to force the evaluation to happen earlier, you could use `ToList()`.

```
var filteredList = myList.Where(a => a.StartsWith("F")).ToList();
```

This means that the evaluation will happen right then and there (and not again).

Answer (score 3):

Because your filteredList is not a list.  It's an IEnumerable generated by LINQ.  It's not a list in of itself, but is a filter that's based off the original.

If you want your filteredList to be an independent list, do this:

```
var filteredList = myList.Where(a => a.StartsWith("F")).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the same reason you get an InvalidOperationException when modifying a collection based on a "Where" (or similar) clause without calling .ToList first.